# Jquery fade function?

Tags: jquery, fadein, fadeout

New to Jquery and wondering how to add a fade function when this happens.

```
function toggleDivs(n) 
{
    // Hide all divs
    var elDivs = document.getElementById('divBlock').getElementsByTagName('div');
    for (var i = 0; i < elDivs.length; i++) 
    {
        elDivs[i].setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
    }

    // Show chosen div
    var elChosen = document.getElementById('project_' + n);
    elChosen.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="divBlock">
<div id="project_1" style="display:block;">
    <figure>
        <a href="#" rel="lightbox">
            <img src="#"  align="left" width="420" height="514" alt="#" />
        </a>
    </figure>
    <article>
        <h4>#</h4>
        <p>Lorem</p>
    </article>
</div>

<div id="project_2" style="display:block;">
    <figure>
        <a href="#" rel="lightbox">
            <img src="#"  align="left" width="420" height="514" alt="#" />
        </a>
    </figure>
    <article>
        <h4>#</h4>
        <p>Lorem</p>
    </article>
</div>
</div>

<a onClick="toggleDivs(1);">Category 1</a>
<a onClick="toggleDivs(2);">Category 2</a>
```

**CSS**

```
#divBlock{
    height:519px;
    width:920px;
    margin-top:130px;
    padding:50px;
}
#divBlock figure{
    float:left;
    border:7px solid #bdd3e4;
    width:420px;
    background:#fff;
    padding:2px;
}
#divBlock figure a{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    display: block;
    height:514px;
    width:420px;
}
#divBlock article{
    height:514px;
    width:460px;
    float:right;
}
#divBlock article h4{
    font-size:26px;
    letter-spacing: -1px;
    text-shadow: 0px 1px 1px #FFF;
    padding:15px 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
    color:#7da8cb;
}
.tech-skills{
    margin-top:20px;
    border-top: 4px dashed rgb(189,211,228);
}
.contentnav{
    width:907px;
    clear: both;
    border-top: 4px dashed rgb(189,211,228);
    padding:10px 5px;
    margin:0px auto;
}
.contentnav  a{
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    display:block;
    height:221px;
    width:190px;
    padding:2px;
    background:#fff;
    float:left;
    border:7px solid #bdd3e4;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    margin-right:25px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.tech-skills-image{
    list-style:none;
}
.tech-skills-image li{
    display:block;
    float:left;
    padding:0px 5px;
    height:120px;
    width:90px;
}    
.tech-skills-image span{
    width:90px;

    float:left;
    text-align:center;
    padding:5px 0px;
}
.tech-skills-image img {
    float:left;
}
```

I would like this page to function with a fade for contents within the divblock. And for the screen to move up as the buttons are located beneath the divblock. On small screens this means manual scrolling up if in order to see the contents. If possible in Jquery id ideally like the border of the active button to change color indicating which contents divblock is displaying.

Comment: Non of the fixes have worked "correctly" I see what you are doing. But while one fades on and the other fades out both are displaying as block for a split of a second, which breaks the site. 
You guys were quick to answer and Im a real noob at this, I did also want to add a scroll up function when this function takes place. 

I will add html+css so you can see what I am trying to do.

Comment: Ok All Fixed now. Thanks for your help!
I added a scroll function and href to the id of my div containing this section, which scrolls it nicely to the top.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using jQuery, you can cut this down quite a bit.

```
function toggleDivs(n) {
    // Hide all divs
    $("#divBlock div").hide();

    // Show chosen div
    $("#project_" + n).show();
}
```

To made it fade instead of just showing and hiding, add a time (in milliseconds) inside the parenthesis following show and hide. For example

```
$("#divBlock div").fadeOut(500); /* take half a second to hide */
```

If you want more control over the effect, look into `.animate()`

```
/* Take 1.5 seconds to hide the div by shortening the height to 0 */ 
$("#divBlock div").animate({ height: "hide"}, 1500);
```

Additional resources

- http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/
- http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/
- http://api.jquery.com/animate/
- http://api.jquery.com/hide/
- http://api.jquery.com/show/
- http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

### Edit

I believe you're looking for the callback function - this calls a function after the function completes. In this case, you'll `fadeIn` "project_n" after all the other divs are finished with `fadeOut`.

```
function toggleDivs(n) {
    // Hide all divs
    $("#divBlock div").fadeOut(500, function(){

        // Show chosen div after others are done fading out
        $("#project_" + n).fadeIn(500);

    });

}
```

Comment: Fixed my css breaking with this. 

    function toggleDivs(n) {
    // Hide all divs
$("#divBlock div").fadeOut(500).delay(500); 
    // Show chosen div
    $("#project_" + n).fadeIn(500).delay(500);
}

Comment: @Alex'Fonz'Bennett I believe you're looking for a callback function - it's a bit cleaner and easier to manage than adding delays.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#divBlock div, #project_'+n).fadeToggle();
```

Comment: You'll need to add jQuery UI in addition to the core jQuery file if you haven't already.

Answer (score 0):

If you want fade effect, simply use [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/), [fadeOut()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/) or [fadeToggle()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeToggle/), it wil show and hide element. you dont need to create another function.

```
function toggleDivs(n) 
{
      $("#divBlock div").fadeOut(); //hiding
      $("#project_" + n).FadeIn(); //showing
}
```